# Adding data to DB using an Axios request yields Internal Server Error

Tags: database, vue.js, axios

I'm creating a form using Vue JS (more specifically the Vuetify library) and when clicking the 'Add' button I am trying to make it so that the user input is added to the database.

The database has 3 columns: id, type_id, value. I want to link the user input to the value column.

Note that allDesserts is an array that stores all of the items in the database. This is what I want to add to.

How can I achieve this?

Component in my form:

```
    <v-combobox
        :items="allDesserts.map(a => a.value)"
        label="Project Type"
        :search-input.sync="search"
    >
        <template v-slot:no-data> 
            <v-text-field
            label="Add new dessert"
            v-model="search"
            >
            </v-text-field>
                <v-btn 
                @click="enterKey"
                >Add</v-btn>
        </template>
    </v-combobox>
```

Axios request/method:

```
        enterKey () {
            axios.post('/api/desserts', {
                value: 'key'
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error.response);
                });
        }
```

My controller:

```
public function storeDessert(Request $request)
{
    $dropdownType = new DropdownType();
    $dropdownType->attribute_id = $request->input(rand(1, 10000));
    $dropdownType->value = $request->input('value');
    $dropdownType->save();
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
"Illegal string offset 'id'"
```

Comment: Problematic code in your controller, not in vue. please check controller code to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is on this line.

```
$dropdownType->attribute_id = $request->input(rand(1, 10000));
```

Let say `rand(1, 10000)` will give you a value of 100, now you used this `100`, as a key to access value in your requests which is not available.

Try to look your payload. You are just passing a data which has a `key value only`, this one.

```
{value: 'key'}
```

and now this line will work cause it is available in your payload.

```
$dropdownType->value = $request->input('value');
```

But not this one.

```
$dropdownType->attribute_id = $request->input(rand(1, 10000));
```